# VS2017, C++ Include Directories vs Additional Include Directories, subfolder includes fail - but why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, include

#include of header file in path C:\yadata.. where the .h file contains further includes.

With nested includes it does not work when putting the path in "Additional Include Directories" but fine in "Include Directories".

The "wrapper" header for the library has some sub references (see sample below) that contains further includes in a nested folder like

```
#include <mCtrl/_defs.h>
#include <mCtrl/html.h> 
and so on.
```

If I in my application do #include  then it only works if I include the directory in VC++ Directories->Include Directories, using C/C++->Additional Directory Includes makes the build fail.

To me it looks like when the path is in "Additional Include Directories" this vs2017 does NOT find  whereas adding the same directory to "Include Directories" makes things work fine.

What is the reason for this behavior - I simply can't find it documented anywhere?

Comment: I have never seen this behavior and I use VS2017 every day at work with 20+ paths in the `Additional Include Directories` for some of my projects.

Comment: Make sure that the folder you add to your include path is the one containing the `mCtrl` folder.

Comment: Also note that in VS project settings are per configuration unless you select more than 1 configuration when changing a value.

Comment: @drescherjm I haven't seen this behavior before. I have made the problem go away by closing the solution, deleting the .vs folder and opening it again.

Comment: You may want to write that as an answer. It could help other readers.

Answer (score 2):

The solution (or rather a fix) was to close VS2017, delete the .vs folder, and open the solution again.